# Add JSON to request

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm new in C# and I have a task to write method which sends JSON as a request. What is the best way to do it? Inside of method it should be like:

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", <<**my JSON**>>, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Here is json example:

```
{
    "externalDealId": "1",
    "dealName": "Test Ver2",
    "dealDba": "Test Ver2",
    "federalId": "12312111",

    "owner1": {
        "fullName": "J1",
        "ssn": "123123220",
        "dateOfBirth": "1988-01-01"
    },
    "owner2": {
        "fullName": "J2",
        "ssn": "123123221",
        "dateOfBirth": "1988-01-02"
    },
    "owner3": {
        "fullName": "J3",
        "ssn": "123123222",
        "dateOfBirth": "1988-01-02"
    }
}
```

Comment: Easier way: https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/getting-started.html#content-type

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to do this is

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                  "\"password\":\"bla\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Well, you could, but OP is using RestSharp which makes the whole process a lot easier and less verbose anyway

Comment: Yes that could be one way of doing that. I have not explored RestSharp yet but will try surely

Answer (score -1):

For c# you can do it like this

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart, Formatting.None);
```

Comment: Where did you get the JavaScript part? It's a C# question. He is sending a request from C#.